# Should I open the same page in every test? Java + Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm new to automated testign and asking for your help.
As I know every test should have its own steps and if I define several tests in one class, should I open the same page several times in each test or I can open it one time somewhere (in first test maybe) and then it will be keeped open all time. Which approach is more correct?

Comment: Try to ask your question here http://sqa.stackexchange.com/ as its not actually about programming

Comment: I would say this is a too broad question, but page load is something that delays your tests and if you can avoid that, I believe it's good doing it. So, I wouldn't access the page for each test if not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say its a better idea to have one WebDriver instance per test, or one entire browser for each test, as your default approach.  I would only try to re-use a WebDriver session if you have a particular test case that might require it and I would say that is generally not very common.